# Is "per person per comment" preferable to "per person, per comment"?

Tags: commas

A piece of legislation can read either "Each Senator is allotted seven minutes per person per comment" or "Each Senator is allotted seven minutes per person, per comment". Are both congruent with standard English usage? Is one preferable to the other?

I would be grateful for sources informing answers.

Comment: We would all be grateful for actual examples informing possible questions.

Comment: Hi, @tchrist, thanks for commenting. I've added an example.

Comment: I've done some research on various forms of "per X per Y" versus "per X, per Y." and I can tell you that—for the period that I've checked so far (1900–1918)—the no-comma style is overwhelmingly more common. But I think I'll delay any further research until I see whether this question is going to stay open or not.

Comment: You need not say "per person" if the only persons speaking are senators.